# Can't get jQuery to execute code in the correct order

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am having some ordering issues. I have some code that does the following:
on page load, loop through 3 tables and grab content from server and populate table with said content
make the table responsive

I am having issues making this work. I can achieve this fine through inspect element (calling functions) but that's not user friendly. I want to know if there's a way I can choose the ordering on what function is being executed.
What I have so far is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (dateCounter == null){ //start calendar from today's date
        var current = new Date();
        dateChange(current, "", 0); //function one to get grab all contents

        //make table responsive
        var switched = false;
              var updateTables = function() {
                if (($(window).width() < 992) && !switched ){
                    console.log("window width < 992px");
                  switched = true;
                  $("table.responsive").each(function(i, element) {
                      console.log("splitting table up");
                    splitTable($(element));
                  });
                  return true;
                }
                else if (switched && ($(window).width() > 992)) {
                  switched = false;
                  $("table.responsive").each(function(i, element) {
                    unsplitTable($(element));
                  });
                }
              };
        function splitTable(original){...}
        function unsplitTable(original){...}
    }
});
```

In theory, on page load, it should populate the table first, then make the table responsive, but that's not the case. It seems to be rendering everything concurrently and therefore I get lots of missing/hidden content in my table. I don't know if the AJAX call in my dateChange function has anything to do preventing my table from displaying content correctly.

Following is a code snippet of the dateChange function:

```
function dateChange(dateInput, nGuests, vName){
    //format dates
    //For each table (3 tables)
    $(".title").each(function(index, element) {
    //prepare HTML for grabbing content from server
        //Grab content from server and pop into table
        $.ajax({
          url: "/grab_Content.asp?boatType="+boatName+"&date="+dateInput+"&guests="+guests+"&boatName="+vName+"",
          dataType:"html",
          success: function(data){
              table.html(data);
          }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: This may explain your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: Call updateTables() inside your dateChange() ajax success callback

Comment: @MarcoMagrini I have tried this approach but I have  .each() in my dateChange function which makes my table very messy unfortunately.

Comment: is the `updateTables` method called on `$(window).resize()` ?

Comment: @ArturFilipiak Yes it is. so if window size is <992px for example, I can call the updateTables and make the table responsive. if >992px, I can call updateTables and make it unresponsive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, AJAX calls are asynchronous.  `$.ajax` returns a promise that you can use to control sequence.  First, return the promise from `dateChange`:

```
function dateChange(dateInput, nGuests, vName){
    return $.ajax({
      //...
    });
}
```

Then when you call it:

```
dateChange(current, "", 0).then(function() {

    //make table responsive
    var switched = false;
    //....
}
```

That will make sure the AJAX call completes before you make the table responsive.

If you have multiple AJAX calls, you'll have to store the promises in an array and use `$.when`:

```
var promises = [];
$('.whatever').each(function() {
    var promise = $.ajax({ /*...*/ });
    promises.push(promise);
});

$.when.apply($, promises).done(function() {
    console.log('all done');
    // do work....
});
```

Note we have to use `Function.prototype.apply` because `$.when` treats an array of promises like a single promise.

Comment: I like this approach, but upon making those changes and running the code, I'm met with the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined" which relates to "dateChange(current, "", 0).then(function() {"

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Either you're using a version of jQuery prior to 1.8, or you're not returning the promise from the `dateChange` function....

Comment: I'm using version 1.9.1

Comment: I also have this:
return $.ajax({
    url: "/availability_Dev/availability_Dev.asp?boatType="+boatName+"&date="+dateInput+"&guests="+guests+"&boatName="+vName+"",
    dataType:"html",
    success: function(data){
     table.html(data);
    }
  });

Comment: Sorry for bad formatting, mind you that $.ajax is in a .each() which means it's being called 3 times. I would imagine that would cause some issues

Comment: So you want all three AJAX requests to complete before you run the responsive code?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Sorry for not specifying earlier. I have 3 tables which I need to populate first, then make responsive

Comment: I corrected a mistake; `$.when`, irritatingly, doesn't treat an array of promises as a list of promises to wait for, so you have to use `Function.prototype.apply`.

Comment: The ordeal with the promises array, is that code I put in my dateChange() function? I only say because I still get the "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined" which I stated previously

Comment: mind you in the dateChange() function, I added the responsive code in the $.when and I seem to be getting somewhere! Which is something. Which means I don't need the dateChange().then(function(){});

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73179/discussion-between-ethan-brown-and-akira-dawson).